# What are the most popular open source build systems nowadays?

Tags: build-process

There are a lot of opensources build systems, and most of them are multiplatform, multilanguage, cross-everything.

I'm not interested on which one is the best (which would be offtopic by the way), but I'd like to know which ones are used most.

So, do we have any kind of statistic about their actual usage? Could you provide any link?

Comment: Apparently cmake seems the only growing trend: http://www.google.com/trends/?q=cmake,+scons,+premake,+gmake&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=3

Comment: Hey, trends may actually be a good option, if you don't need axact data, but dont try "ant" and "make" :)

Comment: "So, do we have any kind of statistic about their actual usage? Could you provide any link?" was a call for references. I was not trying to debate. Well in the end this question hasn't became very popular either...

Comment: For my [master’s thesis](http://andrew.neitsch.ca/msc), in order to be able to answer these sorts of questions, I wrote some code to index the contents of all the source code for every package in Ubuntu. The only statistic I can easily look up right now is that “autotools is used in more than half of all Ubuntu packages that contain any C files at all.” But if you’re still interested in this question, let me know, and I will look into getting the code running again and/or open-sourcing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no tracking process, I doubt that this kind of information is available. You could check the number of artifacts in [maven central](http://mvnrepository.com/search.html) for example, but it won't tell that much about actual usage and may be viewed rather as a trend. Some build tool developers list some of the most reknowned users on their sites, most don't